# Display JSON Values from a File on a Table in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to display information from a JSON file to a table in a Blade template. The problem is, the value I need to display is a result of two values eg...

```
@if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'nehCW5s6Hx4') 
    {{ $data['value'] }} 
@else 
    0 
@endif
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "dataSet": "Hwcn7ajwZ1p",
    "completeDate": "",
    "orgUnit": "100097-5",
    "period": "2016Q4",
    "dataValues": [
        {
            "dataElement": "G1Xh1qsVqKJ",
            "value": "244",
            "storedBy": "ctcUser",
            "timeStamp": "2017-01-04",
            "categoryOptionCombo": "YpFuX3wm6r8",
            "attributeOptionCombo": "uGIJ6IdkP7Q"
        },
        {
            "dataElement": "G1Xh1qsVqKJ",
            "value": "339",
            "storedBy": "ctcUser",
            "timeStamp": "2017-01-04",
            "categoryOptionCombo": "Xns0ysCNhcv",
            "attributeOptionCombo": "uGIJ6IdkP7Q"
        },
        {
            "dataElement": "G1Xh1qsVqKJ",
            "value": "5789",
            "storedBy": "ctcUser",
            "timeStamp": "2017-01-04",
            "categoryOptionCombo": "OKxxCNhyCrd",
            "attributeOptionCombo": "uGIJ6IdkP7Q"
        },
    ...
    ] 
}
```

**Table I want to display to:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center">Indicator</th>
        <th class="text-center">Total</th>
        <th class="text-center" colspan="5">Males</th>
        <th class="text-center" colspan="5">Females</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th> < 1 year</th>
        <th> 1-4 years</th>
        <th> 5-14years</th>
        <th> > 15 years</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th> < 1 year</th>
        <th> 1-4 years</th>
        <th> 5-15 years</th>
        <th> > 15 years</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="12"><b>HIV CARE (Pre ART and ART)</b></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        @foreach($json['dataValues'] as $data)
            @if($data['dataElement'] == 'G1Xh1qsVqKJ')
                <td># <b>1.1 Cumulative number of persons ever enrolled in care at this facility at beginning of the
                        reporting quarter</b></td>
                <td>@if($data['value'] != '') {{ $data['value'] }} @else 0 @endif</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>@if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'nehCW5s6Hx4') {{ $data['value'] }} @else 0 @endif</td>
                <td>@if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'ttFf9vc6pnB') {{ $data['value'] }} @else 0 @endif</td>
                <td>@if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'DNqn8VIZxhn') {{ $data['value'] }} @else 0 @endif</td>
                <td>@if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'ZRSSGOzZeT0') {{ $data['value'] }} @else 0 @endif</td>
                <td>@if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'IR5epaaFjxT') {{ $data['value'] }} @else 0 @endif</td>
                <td>@if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'YpFuX3wm6r8') {{ $data['value'] }} @else 0 @endif</td>
                <td>@if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'Oua3ZLWhBIg') {{ $data['value'] }} @else 0 @endif</td>
                <td>@if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'z9VAozP1BEu') {{ $data['value'] }} @else 0 @endif</td>

            @endif
        @endforeach
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Currently I can pull values inside dataValues, but I can't display the data on a single row, instead, each data is being displayed in its own row:

[**How it displays now**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rECgV.png)
[image]

[**How I want it to display**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odMtK.png)
[image]

Comment: how you want to display it??

Comment: all values on one row instead of displaying each on different rows as on the image

Comment: then use `<tr>` outside foreach loop

Comment: tried, it doesnt work also

Comment: update your question with what you are getting and what you want with sample data

Comment: i have added an image of how i want it to display...

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a lot of changes, I have modified your code, try to adjust it according to your need.

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center">Indicator</th>
        <th class="text-center">Total</th>
        <th class="text-center" colspan="5">Males</th>
        <th class="text-center" colspan="5">Females</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        @foreach($json['dataValues'] as $data)

            @if($data['dataElement'] == 'G1Xh1qsVqKJ')
                <th></th>
                @if($data['value'] != '')
                    <td>
                    <th>Total</th>  </td> @endif
                @if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'nehCW5s6Hx4')
                    <th> < 1 year</th>@endif
                @if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'ttFf9vc6pnB')
                    <th> 1-4 years</th>@endif
                @if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'DNqn8VIZxhn')
                    <th> 5-14years</th>@endif
                @if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'ZRSSGOzZeT0')
                    <th> > 15 years</th>@endif
                @if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'IR5epaaFjxT')
                    <th> < 1 year</th>@endif
                @if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'YpFuX3wm6r8')
                    <th> 1-4 years</th>@endif
                @if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'Oua3ZLWhBIg')
                    <th> 5-15 years</th>@endif
                @if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'z9VAozP1BEu')
                    <th> > 15 years</th>@endif
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="12"><b>HIV CARE (Pre ART and ART)</b></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        @foreach($json['dataValues'] as $data)

            <?php $count = 0;?>
            @if($data['dataElement'] == 'G1Xh1qsVqKJ')

                <?php $count++;?>
                @if($count==1)
                    <td># <b>1.1 Cumulative number of persons ever enrolled in care at this facility at beginning of
                            the
                            reporting quarter</b></td>
                @endif
                @if($data['value'] != '')
                    <td> {{ $data['value'] }}  </td> @endif
                @if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'nehCW5s6Hx4')
                    <td> {{ $data['value'] }}</td>@endif
                @if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'ttFf9vc6pnB')
                    <td> {{ $data['value'] }} </td>@endif
                @if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'DNqn8VIZxhn')
                    <td> {{ $data['value'] }} </td>@endif
                @if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'ZRSSGOzZeT0')
                    <td> {{ $data['value'] }} </td>@endif
                @if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'IR5epaaFjxT')
                    <td> {{ $data['value'] }} </td>@endif
                @if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'YpFuX3wm6r8')
                    <td> {{ $data['value'] }} </td>@endif
                @if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'Oua3ZLWhBIg')
                    <td> {{ $data['value'] }} </td>@endif
                @if($data['categoryOptionCombo'] == 'z9VAozP1BEu')
                    <td> {{ $data['value'] }} </td>@endif

            @endif
        @endforeach
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a normal foreach loop:

```
@foreach($results as $result) {{$result->fieldname}} @endforeach
```